# Call to undefined function result()

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting this error in my view file. Here is my code please do help me out and tell what to do?

```
<?php 
//foreach($records->result() as $row):
foreach(result() as $row):
 echo $row->title;
endforeach;
?>
```

Here is my controller file:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Hello extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('hello_model');
        $data['records']=$this->hello_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('you_view',$data);
        //$this->load->view('you_view');
    }
}
?>
```

I am posting here my model file also. Ihv tried some by me, but still getiing this error. Dnt knw wt to do.

```
<?php

class Hello_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAll()
    {
    $q=$this->db->get('test'); // query where 'test' is table name.

        if($q->num_rows()>0)
        {
           foreach ($q->result() as $row)
           {
              $data[]=$row;
           }
        return $data;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: In your Model, after checking `num_rows`, return `$q->result_array();`

Comment: why did you use `$q->result()` if you want to return the result as an array??? :D It is good to see the [instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

Comment: thnx for answering frnd...but its working now.....i used $records in place of result() in view file :)

Comment: Yes but please notice that you are fetching the result as an object and making an array manually ! use `$q->result_array();` instead. good luck.

Comment: sure hashem qolami i will.....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$records` already holds your data so this should work:

```
foreach($records as $row){
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Comment: oh!!!!! thank u soooo much Mudshark. It worked like charm. Thanx for giving time u too muhammet :) cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use result() in your view,because in your model you already did.

Just try this:

```
 <?php 
 foreach($records as $row):
 echo $row->title;
 endforeach;
 ?>
```

Comment: You just can't use result() function by itself. You have to use it with a variable that holds result().

Comment: ya i hv chnaged that muhammet...its working now....thank u soo much for giving time :) tkcre